# Django: the information is not processed for a given condition if

Tags: django, django-filter

Template tag {% if %}  {% endif %} does't work correctly. I need to make the search results on the page appear only after the search query. But for some reason, when the page loads, all existing content appears at once. But after get request filter works correctly.

**views.py**

```
 def search(request):
        place_list = Places.objects.all()
        place_filter = PlaceFilter(request.GET, queryset=place_list)
        return render(request, 'search/user_list.html', {'filter': place_filter})
```

html

```
{% if filter.qs %}

<div class="row">
    {% for obj in filter.qs %}
    <div class="col-md-3 admin__block">
    <div class="cover__wrapper">
    <img src="{{ obj.main_photo.url }}" alt="">
    <a href="#"><span>#</span>{{ obj.name }}</a>
    <p>{{ obj.description }}</p>
    </div>                  
    </div>
    {% endfor %}        
</div>

{% endif %}
```

**filters.py**

```
class PlaceFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    name = django_filters.CharFilter(lookup_expr='icontains', widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={
            'placeholder': 'Search place', 'class': 'input__search'}))
    class Meta:
        model = Places
        fields = ['name']
```

Comment: Can you add `PlaceFilter` class?

Comment: @neverwalkaloner, I updated the question

Comment: Why would you expect content not to appear? Your view passes `request.GET` to the filter; this is empty on first load, so no filtering is done and all the content is shown. This doesn't have anything to do with the if tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`FilterSet`'s `qs` property returns filterset's `queryset`. So it's always `True`. 
You can use `request.GET` in template to check if `GET` contains any request data and render only filtered data:

```
{% if request.GET %}

<div class="row">
    {% for obj in filter.qs %}
    <div class="col-md-3 admin__block">
    <div class="cover__wrapper">
    <img src="{{ obj.main_photo.url }}" alt="">
    <a href="#"><span>#</span>{{ obj.name }}</a>
    <p>{{ obj.description }}</p>
    </div>                  
    </div>
    {% endfor %}        
</div>

{% endif %}
```